# Wireshark data interpretation

Tags: perl, wireshark

I am using WWW::Mechanize module in perl to create a script which goes to another website and downloads data. When I manually go to website and download data (using firefox browser) I can capture the packets in well-readable format using http-fox addon.

[image]

But, when I run perl script doing same thing and try to capture packets using Wireshark I can not understand how to understand the captured packets. All the information which was available in above diagram (firefox) is missing in wireshark.

[image: Wireshark packet catpture]

Also, when I click "follow-stream". I get dotted text. Like this:

[image]

How to interpret this? May be the data is encrypted. In this case how to get the RSA key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> May be the data is encrypted

The packets in the TCP connection before packet 8 are to or from the "https" port (port 443), and packets 5 and 6 are a "TLSv1 Client Hello" and a "TLSv2 Server Hello", respectively, so this is HTTP-over-TLS traffic, which is likely to be encrypted.

Your browse is probably logging *decrypted* HTTP-over-SSL traffic in the http-fox module, but Wireshark is capturing the traffic going on the network, which is *encrypted* traffic.

See [the Wireshark Wiki page on SSL](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL) for some information on how to have Wireshark decrypt that traffic in some cases.